# Find a lower bound for the minimax risk $\displaystyle \min_{\delta}\max_{\theta\in\Omega}EL(\theta,\delta(X))\ge1-\frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: self-study, expectation-maximization, decision-theory

Consider a random binary vector $X\in\{0,1\}^n. $Let $\theta\in\Omega$ be a probability vector in $\mathbb R^{2^n}$ with $X\sim\theta$. Consider the loss function $\displaystyle L(\theta,a)=\max_{x\in\{0,1\}^n}|\theta_x-a_x|=\Vert\theta-a\Vert_\infty$. Let $\delta:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\Omega$ be a decision rule. Conclude that the minimax risk is lower bounded as follows:

$\displaystyle \min_{\delta}\max_{\theta\in\Omega}EL(\theta,\delta(X))\ge1-\frac{1}{2^n}$

Current work:

I observe that the answer is in the form of $1-\displaystyle \frac{1}{\dim {\mathbb R^{2^n}}}$. But I am not good at the max and Expectation things in a step by step fashion.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. I don't think this has much to do with [EM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm). But an easy way to get minimax lower bounds is by adding a prior. Suppose $\vartheta$ is a rv over the range of $\theta$. Then,

$$
\min_\delta\max_\theta \mathbb{E}_X[L(\theta,\delta)]\ge 
\min_\delta\mathbb{E}_\vartheta \mathbb{E}_X[L(\vartheta,\delta)]\,\,.
$$

Under what choice of prior for $\vartheta$ can we (1) compute the integral on the RHS with no knowledge of $\delta$ and (2) what is that integral?

Comment: Not too familiar. A uniform distribution is simple. I think I’ve seen the loss function represented as an integral but not sure how it would look here.

Comment: RHS=$\min_\delta\int_0^1EL(\vartheta,\delta)d\vartheta$?